# How to compare URL with any number?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to compare URL with javascript the current url is:

```
http://domain/products?save&step&id=287
```

I used  window.location.search, it rendered:

```
?save&step&id=287
```

I need to know how to compare URL with any number like this pseudocode, I used (any_number) as example of random number, it doesn't need to match equal number since I had no idea which is properly method.

```
 var prod_url = window.location.search;

 if(prod_url == "?save&step&id="+(any_number){    
  alert("URL is matched");
 }
```

I'm open with all suggestions, any method with excepted result is welcome.

Comment: The search term you are looking for is *regular expression*

Comment: easy `if ( any_number == prod_url.split("=").pop() )`

Comment: @adeneo well, it would be a bad practice if some urls have more than 2 "=" 's

Comment: @Ivan - considering most of the answers, and the OP, is comparing the querystring as a literal without any parsing, just assuming the number is at the end is three steps better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
var prod_url = "?save&step&id=12345";
if (/\?save\&step\&id=[0-9]+$/.test(prod_url)) {
  alert("URL is matched");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For comparing a string with a regular expression, you have to use the [match()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) function.

An example for matching "any number" would be:

```
myString.match(/[0-9]+/);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

So your if statement woulf be something like this:

```
if ((/\\?save&step&id=\d/).test(prod_url)) {    
  alert("URL is matched");
}
```

This should give you true for any number.

Comment: Why "any_number" is there? it's undefined variable.

Comment: Sorry corrected that. prod_url is the string with the random number at the end i guess.